# How to check if 3 numbers are a Pythagorean triple?

Tags: c, pythagorean

How we could get three numbers without ordering and then check if they form a Pythagorean triple or not?

So, `pythagorean(3, 4, 5)` or `pythagorean(5, 3, 4)` will print/return true, while `pythagorean(4, 3, 6)` will print/return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this algotrithm :

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  int main(){
long long int a, b, c ;
scanf("%llu %llu %llu", &a, &b, &c);

if (a*a==b*b+c*c || b*b==a*a+c*c || c*c==a*a+b*b)
{
    printf("YES");
}

else
    printf("NO");
   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: yeh that is working thank you

Answer (score -1):

If you use the equation, a^2 + b^2 = c^2, c should be the largest number and the order of a and b should not matter. Just find the largest number, set that equal to c, and then set the other two values to a and b and check to see if the equality is true.